# How can I POST a request the following structure?

Tags: php, node.js, post

My backend (NodeJS) expects to receive a request with the following data format in order to create a document in my database (MongoDB)

```
{
    "Name": "John Doe",
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "Item A",
            "price": 100,
        },
        {
            "name": "Item B",
            "price": 250,
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to create a request in PHP (WordPress) with this structure, and send it to my server.
This is the code I currently have:

```
    $body = (object)array('Name' => 'John Doe', 'items' => array(
      array("name" => "Item A", "price" => 5000),
      array("name" => "Item B", "price" => 5000),
    ));
```

But this doesn't work and I'd appreciate some help because I didn't write php in 10 years

Comment: Full php code, especially request sending part would help a lot.

Comment: Thanks @Mihail0v it appeared that I was missing some configuration. Answer is posted below, thank you for trying to help me!

Comment: Made it clearer. I found it understandable though

Answer (score 0):

Ok looks like what I was missing was a little configuration of my request.

Answer for whoever finds it helpful:

```
  $url = "http://example.com";
    $body = array('name' => 'John Doe', 'items' => array(
      array("name" => "Item A", "price" => 5000),
      array("name" => "Item B", "price" => 5000),
    ));

    $body = json_encode($body);

    print_r($body);

    $response = wp_remote_post($url, array(
      'headers'     => array('Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8'),
      'body'    => $body,
      'method'      => 'POST',
      'data_format' => 'body'
    ));
```

Comment: I don't see any problem here, unless wrong 'name' letter case. Probably the problem is on nodejs side, does it throws any errors for your query? And check the $response output for any information.